# How to show all log (all commit) for all project in repo?

Tags: git, repo

I hava a manifest project include several projects in git-repo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="*"/>
  <default revision="master" sync-c="true" sync-j="2"/>
    <project name="Test1" path="application"/>
    <project name="Test2" path="others" />
</manifest>
```

After repo sync, I want to show git log for all commit in all project,
so I use:

```
repo forall -c git log
```

This should output all the commits but actually only show the latest commits.

```
project application/
commit 8612d2035bd90ed50476a7941ffe9c603c668ec8
Author: ben
Date:   Fri Jun 5 10:21:17 2020 +0800

    update first version

project others/
commit 488c02845ff987c04071bac5111b0fccce8fa8ab
Author: ben
Date:   Fri Jun 5 16:20:54 2020 +0800

    create file class_C.c
```

Try to add some tag of git log but still show latest commit only.
If just clone one project not by repo, use "git log" could show all commit.

How to show all commit for all project in repo?

Comment: Try `repo forall -c git log --all`

Answer (score 0):

In plain old git? `git log --all` and feel free to use more options line --oneline and/or --graph

Comment: This shows log for one repository. The OP asks about many repos in one project. `repo` is a tool to work with projects that consist of multiple repos.